# What are signs at tourist locations known as?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an official name for the signs you find at tourist locations?

Example - a sign at the head of a trail that may show the trail maps, the name of the trail/area and maybe some historical or geological information?

Another example is a sign at a scenic outlook that explains what can be seen from the viewpoint.

Example sentence - I'll meet you at the '??' sign near the parking lot.

Comment: I would use "placard" as a generic term, though you can get more specific for individual cases.

Comment: @HotLicks I was thinking placard as well but when searching for placards of known tourist areas I wasn't getting a lot of results for the more full-sized, information signs that I've since come to believe are known as interpretive signs.

Comment: how about a plain 'sign' whose meaning will be made clear when seen and read.

Comment: @lbf Just plain 'sign' has served me well this past week but I've found a few instances where something more specific was needed. In my example sentence, for example, if the parking lot is large and their are three obvious signs, one a welcome sign, another a large no parking sign and the one I mean, an interpretive sign, the people meeting may end up at different signs on either end of the parking lot and out of sight from(of?) each other.

Comment: For what it's worth, the signs you're referring to have nothing to do with tourists *per se*.  They are also used for native residents of an area who have visited on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 1):

Interpretive Sign

I think I've answered this myself as I was writing the question. I'll leave it up as searching for it with the word combinations I was didn't give me any immediate answers and the way this question is worded may help future googlers.

For similar and related sign names here are a couple..

Interpretive Panel - seems to be used by some as a synonym, though the examples on [this website](https://www.behrendsgroup.com/interpretive-panels-things-consider-designing-signage/) are similar to what I would call plaques.

[Commemorative Plaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commemorative_plaque) - These are sometimes similar to interpretive signs but seem to offer less graphical interpretation. Also called historical markers or historic plaques.

[Tourist Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourist_sign) - road signs with uniform appearance and color for directing tourists to major tourist attractions. It seems that in many countries they are known as brown signs.

[Welcome Sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_sign) - these are the signs welcoming visitors to a city, park, state, province or any location with boundaries that are found on major road entrances to the location.

Comment: Yes. And if you need more complete terminology, try [here](https://www.fs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/stelprd3810021.pdf)

Comment: [This site](https://www.travelwayfinding.com/what-is-heritage-interpretation/) has the best summary of this that I found.

Comment: Please add attributed supporting evidence to answers on ELU.  Answers lacking such come across as (and may merely be) just opinion or localisms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't seem to find any official definitions of 'interpretive sign' or I would have. However, a Google search turns up dozens (at least) of SERP's filled with sign making and related companies using the word to advertise their interpretive sign design, creation and erection services. This week I'll consider creating a Wikipedia entry for it when I have more time to better research them properly.

Comment: @PhilSweet Thanks Phil, that PDF has given me some new vocabulary to work with.